# Connect to SQL Server through SSH tunnel using tiny_tds in Ruby

Tags: sql-server, ruby, tiny-tds

I try to connect to the remote SQL Server 2008 R2 using [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) Ruby gem through SSH tunnel, like this:

```
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'net/ssh/gateway'

gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(
  'host',
  'username',
  port: 'port',
  password: 'password'
)
port = gateway.open('127.0.0.1', 1433, 1234) # SQL Server uses 1433 port

db_client = TinyTds::Client.new(
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  port: 1234,
  database: 'database'
) # => TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out (127.0.0.1:1234)
```

I get the exception above. Although, if I try to SSH to the Windows machine from the console and try to connect to the SQL Server using `sqlcmd` - everything works just fine.